# How can i inject a service into a provider where the service is within a module passed into the providers module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

How can i inject a service within my shared module into my core module?

I'm having trouble injecting PersistSettingsService into LocalisationProvider Localisation is in the core module and Persist is in the shared module these are set up like so.

```
const Core =
    angular
        .module('core', [Auth, Shared])
        .constant('moment', moment)
        .service('ModuleLazyLoaderService', ModuleLazyLoaderService)
        .service('PermissionsService', PermissionsService)
        .service('PersistSettingsService', PersistSettingsService)
        .provider('ModuleLazyLoaderState', ModuleLazyLoaderStateProvider)
        .provider('Localisation', LocalisationProvider)
        .config(config)
        .run(run);
```

I've removed a lot from shared as there are a lot of items added to shared

```
const Shared = angular
    .module('shared', [])
    .service('PersistSettingsService', PersistSettingsService)
```

This results in

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: Error: $injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module core due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: PersistSettingsService
```

From my understanding shared should be included within core so I should be able to inject it in. I've tried setting it to a provider but this didn't resolve the issue.

I have my Provider class.

```
export default class LocalisationProvider {
    $get() {
        return {
             getDateFormat: () => this.getDateFormat(),
             getSetFormat: () => this.getSetFormat(),
             getTimeFormat: () => this.getTimeFormat(),
             setDateFormat: value => this.setDateFormat(value),
             setTimeFormat: value => this.setTimeFormat(value)
        }; 
    }

    constructor(PersistSettingsService) {
      'ngInject';
       this.persistSettingsService = PersistSettingsService;
   }
}
```

I have made sure all 'ngInject' are present any help would be appreciated.

I have created a reproducible version but to be honest I'm not sure they're failing for the same reasons.

https://jsfiddle.net/panf8L6s/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not inject a service into the provider itself. Injecting a service into a provider's $get method is the same as injecting a service into a factory, but you can not inject it into the provider function directly.

But I resolved this issue by refactoring out the provider logic into a service then injecting that into my providers $get method like so:

```
export default class LocalisationProvider {
  $get(LocalisationController) {
    'ngInject';
    this.localisationController = LocalisationController;
    this.getDateFormat = () => this.localisationController.getDateFormat();
    return {
      getDateFormat: () => this.getDateFormat(),
      getSetFormat: () => this.localisationController.getSetFormat(),
      getTimeFormat: () => this.localisationController.getSetFormat(),
      setDateFormat: value => this.localisationController.setDateFormat(value),
      setTimeFormat: value => this.localisationController.setTimeFormat(value)
    };
  }
}
```

The reason getDateFormat is both outside the get and inside is because the provider runs during the module loading phase whereas the $get is run when instantiating the service you are providing.